# How to put IDispatch::Invoke to a MFC C++ Thread?

Tags: multithreading, visual-c++, mfc, createthread

How to put the `IDispatch::Invoke` to a thread and call `TerminateThread` if it timeouts?

The reason I wanted to do this is because I find that sometimes the Invoke call will go into infinity loop and never return anything and hence the call will just sit there for forever. Hence, I am thinking of putting the Invoke to a thread and terminate the thread when it timeout.

Any advices or references are really appreciated.
Peace

Answer (score 0):

Hi i strongly do not recommend you call TerminateThread for any others things but TerminateThread + IDispatch::Invoke can cause abnormal program termination in good case and more strange program behavior and random crashes in bad one. I think you need chose another way...

Comment: Hi Sanja, Thank you for your reply and advice. Yes, I had read in google not to call TerminateThread and the Invoke together. But, aside from creating Thtread, I could not think or find other way to determine the timeout of the IDispatch::Invoke and the call for the function will sit there for forever.